# Storing a large but low-rank matrix efficiently

Tags: r, matrix, rank, cran

I know there are packages in R to store sparse matrices efficiently. Is there also a way to store a low-rank matrix efficiently? For example:

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), nrow=1e5, ncol=1e1)
B <- A %*% t(A)
```

Now, `B` is too large to store in memory, but it is low in rank. Is there any way to construct and store `B` in an efficient way, such that some basic read methods (`rowSums`, `colSums`, etc) are performed on the fly, in order to trade for cpu or memory?

Comment: Interesting question- what applications would it have? (Where do low rank matrices generally appear?)

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Those matrices are used, for instance, as approximations of large dense matrices (too large to compute, or even to store), in some [optimization algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS).

Comment: If you are willing to approximate B, could you use a low-dimensional approximation, e.g. use a SVD and keep the first n dimensions of the SVD?

Not sure this is quite what you want, but might be worth considering.

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, the following seems somewhat relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92328/low-rank-matrix-factorization

Comment: Yes, I agree with above comment. Factor it, and it will become sparse.

Comment: This might be of help: http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee378b/papers/achlioptas-mcsherry-LRMatrixApprox.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Your question is already the answer: To store such a low rank matrix efficiently, you make a data structure containing both factors. If matrix-vector multiplication is required, it can be done from right to left using matrix-vector products of the factors.

One application of this strategy and data structure can be found in implementations of limited-memory Broyden or BFGS quasi-Newton methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, although I miss the experience to know how efficient this would be for large matrices:

If the rank is low, it means the matrix contains many irrelevant lines, which are linear combinations of others. If the matrix represents a linear system of equations, one could design an algorithm, which successively removes those lines.

To check if a line is irrelevant, check if the rank of the matrix without that line is still the same. For computing the matrix rank, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473983/calculate-matrix-rank-using-scipy/6900786#6900786) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473983/calculate-matrix-rank-using-scipy/3356123#3356123) answer.

Comment: That basically sounds like a very expensive way of factoring :-)

Comment: Sorry, but a terribly poor idea that works only for a simple case, with replicated rows. In fact, it is TRIVIAL to generate a matrix of rank 1, that has NO replicate rows or columns. Thus pick random row vectors U and V, then U'*V has rank 1.