# remove independent row or column of a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

I have to solve Ax=b . I believe that python library to solve under determined system / over determined system of equation is different.
Is there a library function in python  which will remove dependent row/column from a matrix so that from the rank of a matrix I could  solve the equation appropriately

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: use numpy , pretty good for this kind of operation

Comment: basically I need to solve Ax=b. But in my case the system can be either under determined or over determined. I found out that over determined system can be solve using a least square method and under determined using least norm method. Therefore I need to know the rank of matrix before solving the system of equations. Therefore my question was in this direction. I request everybody to correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Determination of a matrix rank is a rather ill-posed problem. The best you can do is to compute the SVD and determine from the progression of the singular values whether there is a sufficient magnitude drop that can be used to determine the rank. But better use the pseudo-inverse or least-square solver provided by numpy as in the answer of user3277291.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) matrix of A denoted as A<sup>+</sup>. A solution exist if and only if AA<sup>+</sup>b = b and all solutions are given by
x = A<sup>+</sup>b + (I - A<sup>+</sup>A)*u

This can be done with numpy.linalg

Example:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6],[8, 10, 12]])
>>> b = np.array([22., 7., 14.])
>>> Ap = np.linalg.pinv(A)
# Check if a solution exist
>>> np.testing.assert_allclose(A.dot(Ap).dot(b),b,rtol=1e-5, atol=0)
>>> x = Ap.dot(b)
>>> print A.dot(x)
[ 22.,   7.,  14.]
```

Alternatively you can use  numpy.linalg.lstsq

Example:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6],[8, 10, 12]])
>>> b = np.array([22., 7., 14.])
>>> x = np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)[0]
>>> print np.dot(A,x)
[ 22.,   7.,  14.]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) to do scientific computing. E.g.:

```
In [23]: import numpy as np

In [24]: a=np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))

In [25]: a
Out[25]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [26]: np.delete(a, 2, axis=1)  #delete the 3rd column
Out[26]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 11],
       [12, 13, 15]])

In [27]: np.rank(a) #this returns the number of dimensions of an array, 
                    #not the concept "rank" in linear algebra, 
Out[27]: 2

In [40]: np.linalg.matrix_rank(a) #this returns matrix rank of array using SVD method
Out[40]: 2
```

On windows, you can get the [unofficial installer here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Another post: [Calculate Matrix Rank using scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473983/calculate-matrix-rank-using-scipy)